# Objective C Regex?

Tags: objective-c, regex

I'm trying to parse a 7-digit number from a page's source code and the pattern that I look for is

/nnnnnnn"

where "n" is a digit. I'm trying with the following regex and in a regex test site it works, but not in obj-c. Is it possible that I'm passing the wrong option or something?

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"/\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\">" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch error:nil];
NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:contents
                                                    options:0
                                                      range:NSMakeRange(0, [contents length])];
```

Comment: You should escape the backslashes themselves with another backslash, like `\\d`. Also, if you need repeating a digit, try `/\\d{7}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should double the backslashes in front of your `d`s, like this:

```
@"/\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\">"
```

Backslash is a special character inside a string literal: the character after it is interpreted differently. In order for the regex engine to see a backslash, you need two slashes in the literal.

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting some results now. But when I add the \" at the end of the regex (if we forget about the > for a moment) I'm not getting any results!

Comment: @NikolayDyankov You do not need to double the slash in front of the double quote character `"`, because a single slash escapes the double quote. The exact string seen by the regex engine is `/\d\d\d\d\d\d\d">`.